# Include confounder into partial least squares regression

Tags: r, confounding, partial-least-squares

I am wondering, when using partial least squares regression to investigate a research question, there is predictor component (T) and response component (U), if I want to adjust for confounders (C), do I just include the C variable in the T component ? I am using R.

Thank you very much!